# Getting conditional probability is more difficult than joint probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, random-variables

While I am studying Variational Inference, I am told that

"In Graphical Model, to get the joint probability, $P(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$, is easy but it is difficult to get the conditional probability $P(X_1|X_2, \dots)$ and variational inference is useful for this case."

Can I have some intuitive explanation about the sentence?

Comment: What's the reference for that quoted statement? Because I feel its the other way around. For example, in graphical models, let's say node A is connected and directed towards node B, then $P(A)$ is associated with node A and $P(B|A)$ is associated with node B. To find joint distribution $P(A,B)$, use the law of total probability, $\sum P(A) P(B|A)$ (for discrete regime).

Comment: Indeed, the other way round because conditional expectations do not require to identify normalizing factors.